# Yarn install for metaplex issue fetching packages

Tags: metaplex

Issue getting metaplex candy machine to run. Seems to be an issue with the dependencies. I have attached a screenshot of the first issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlgeP.png)

Comment: Can you try just using `yarn` inside the `metaplex/js` folder? use `cd` to change the directory into the `js` folder of metaplex (or metaplex-master) and then run `yarn`

Comment: Please, do not use screen shots for an error message : instead, copy and paste the message. People won't have to click to see the message, visually impaired people will be able to read it, and the message will be indexed by search engines (allowing people with the same error to find your question and its answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Yarn in js/packages/common